How to Programmatically Open a Flutter App When It Is in Background or Terminated State Upon Receiving a Call Notification?
I'm developing a Flutter app where I need to handle incoming call notifications. Specifically, when the app receives a calling notification while it is in the background or terminated state, I want to programmatically open the app and navigate directly to a specific screen (e.g., an incoming call screen).
I've implemented the call notification using flutter_local_notifications, but I'm unsure how to achieve the functionality where the app automatically opens when the notification is received, especially if the app is not currently running.
Key Requirements:

The app should open automatically when the call notification is received.

It should navigate directly to the incoming call screen.

The solution should work on Android, and if possible, on iOS as well.


Things I've Tried:

I've set up a MethodChannel to handle native code execution, but I need guidance on how to properly wake up the app from the background or terminated state.

Question: How can I achieve this functionality in Flutter? Is there a specific approach or library that supports this use case?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
